# i have process it search in all dir in hard drive its take about 15 min

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

i have process it search in all dir in hard drive its take about 15 min how i run parallel with normal  process in web

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private RapetsDbContext db = new RapetsDbContext();
   public HomeController()
    {
  // i try to call it here with Parallel.Invoke  but  the index waiting  my  dirs() func  to end  

       Parallel.Invoke(() => Index(), () => helperCodes.dirs());
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Why are you multithreading? You do know it will make it slower, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Ctor i user  Task.Factory.StartNew

```
 public HomeController()
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EnitiyGetWorks.GetWorks());
            }
```

thinks Botonomous for your help your post was the good answer

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the main thread because of the code in HomeController's constructor:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => Index(), () => helperCodes.dirs());
```

Until that parallel is done, the main thread is blocked.

Now to simply unblock the main thread and address your question, you could do:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(helperCodes.dirs(), (item) =>

                {
                        // Do something with the dir
                });
            });
```

which wouldn't block the Ctor from finishing, then you can access Index().

You won't be able to get the task status unless you expose the task as a field or write something to get the task's status. I wouldn't recommend this approach but would write a class to handle this.

Comment: thanks for comment but where can i use this  i try it in const but not run too

 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(helperCodes.dirs(), (item) =>

                {
                        // Do something with the dir
                });
            });

Comment: You should use the `StartNew` with caution, and to guarantee that it will run in thread pool you should use `Task.Run`

Comment: "Until that parallel is done, the main thread is blocked." It is a web server HTTP request. a) The main thread is on the client, and that isn't blocked. b) You should NEVER start work on a background thread on ASP, as the web server will kill it off.

Comment: @Aron Yeah but it was in the ctor if you look. SO the main thread WILL be blocked until that parallel was done if not nested in a task. I don't advocate this approach but it does fix OP's issue.

Comment: @VMAtm why would using StartNew not guarantee the Task will be scheduled on at thread pool?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html - this article provides such sitation.

Comment: @VMAtm thanks for the link. I can see how using StartNew is confusing when not understanding the overloads and when mixing with Async delegates. But there is no Async delegate in this case, just a sync delegate represented by a task. It may be good practice however to recommend Task.Run as you have for general purpose.  It also does not make this answer wrong. You will also see on that article that when running parallel execution, StartNew() is the recommend approach.   Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, I just added a record abount article, nothing more :)